# Reduce voltage going from absolute encoder to MCU

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, resistors, encoder

My absolute encoder need 24VDD (minimum is 11v) and send the same VDD to the output pin.
But My MCU only tolerate 3.3v or 5v
I could use a resistor but if the amp slightly change for any reason, it could be a problem for my MCU.

I was considering using a MOSFET, what do you think? is it better?
I'm not familiar with this kind of stuff
THank you

[image]

Encoder datasheet:
http://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Reference=W915601910811&p_EnDocType=Instruction%20sheet&p_File_Id=1391814451&p_File_Name=W915601910811_A06.pdf

Comment: Sorry. can't understand what are you trying to say...please be clear and if schematic is there, it will be helpful

Comment: I will try to be clearer:
i have 6 output pin on my absolute encoder.
State high is 24vdd, state low is 0v
And the state is always changing on each pin as the encoder is moving.
I saw that if I use a resistor, the voltage will drop but depending of amp going through, the voltage will change.

In order to not damage my MCU receiving voltage from the output pins of the encoder, i was considering using MOSFET. If it OK?

Comment: Please provide link to encoder datasheet.  You can probably use a resistive voltage divider.

Comment: Please edit your question and add those details to it. Don't add details in comments. Otherwise you're expecting people to piece it all together in their head. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: I edited the first post

Comment: OP, your datasheet shows 4 different versions.  Which specific part number do you have?

Comment: sorry the comment with my answer has been deleted:
XCC MG6G0604N

Comment: Your concern about the current changing the voltage drop is valid for a single resistor (in fact subsequent to transition the current would be normally zero, if it wasn't in the process of damaging the MCU), which is why resistor based solutions use two resistors in the form of a voltage divider.  By forming a complete path to ground, these set their own current and voltage drop, they can be pulled by current drawn by a load, but generally once the input capacitance is charged that is minuscule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading your question and looking at the encoder data sheet it is clear that your encoder is equipped with what is called the "PNP output". That style of output will source current from the device positive supply for one logic state and shut that current off for the other logic state. To accommodate that type of encoder output you need to give your MCU an "NPN input" type circuit. There are a number of ways to do this with various types of circuits, components and chips.

Possibly the simplest and most robust circuit to deal with this would be to use the following idea if you do not mind using low cost discrete components.

[image]

The diode D1 is placed in the circuit to protect the NPN transistor in the case that there are negative spikes on the wire from the encoder due to disturbance from other machine parts.

This circuit will work well for most speeds that the encoder would operate at and you would only use single ended outputs from the encoder. If your encoder has a high line count and operates up toward its maximum RPM then you may find that the PNP/NPN type connections may not provide fast enough switching performance. It those cases you will want to use the differential output pairs for the A, B and 0 outputs of the encoder and get the part that has the 5V diff pair driver outputs. Then your MCU side would use a differential receiver for the signals such as shown in the encoder data sheet:

[image]

Comment: The differential drive version might also be required if your cable is long; it will have much better noise immunity.

Comment: This looks good. Thank you. What about using a simple optocoupler? It should do the trick isn't it?

Comment: @vib - The simple opto-coupler can work as well but is really only necessary if you need galvanic isolation between the machine where the encoder is mounted and where your MCU is located. Also keep in mind that most "simple" optocouplers will also cost more and limit the maximum switching frequency even more than the simple NPN circuit shown above.

Answer (score -1):

I have used basic diode an pull up resistor in the past.
[image: simple diode level shift]

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer?